# Salesforce Apex not updating record

Tags: salesforce, apex, apex-code

I am trying to do a simple update in sandbox on a field that is in the Account Object in Salesforce but it does not seem like it is committing. I follow the basics of pulling and updating a record as stated below:

```
String accountId = '12345'
Account queriedAccount = [SELECT Id, Communication_Bubble__c FROM Account WHERE id = :accountId limit 1];
System.debug(queriedAccount);

// set the field i want to update
queriedAccount.Communication_Bubble__c = 'New Donor';

// update field
update queriedAccount;

// run select again to see if update went through
Account queriedAccount2 = [SELECT Id, Communication_Bubble__c FROM Account WHERE id = :accountId limit 1];
System.debug(queriedAccount2);
```

Looking at the logs after this piece of code is ran shows that the update went through as I was able to pull the account and it displays the Account with the updated field. Here are what both of the debugs display:

Debug1: *|Debug|Account:{Id=12345}* (communication bubble is null)

Debug2: *|Debug|Account:{Id=12345,Communication_Bubble=New Donor}*

From the above it seems like the update is working exactly how it should be. But when I go to the account in the dashboard, or pull the account with a query in the developer console that Communication Bubble field is still blank.

It seems like I am missing some sort of commit but I cant figure out what it is.

Answer (score 0):

No way this compiles, did you anonymise it too much?

1. `Communication_Bubble` - actual field name is probably `Communication_Bubble__c`.
2. You query and set a field value on `queriedAccount` but what you actually save is another variable `queriedContact`?

There's low chance you actually have some code that resets the value (would have to be `@future`, time-based workflow etc to work but not be detected in 2nd query... But my vote goes to "you just updated wrong record"

Comment: Thats my bad. Both of what you pointed out were mistakes on my end and the code is now correct with how it is in apex. But it still doesnt update the record.

Comment: When you run it in Developer Console - does it generate just 1 debug log or is there more with "FutureHandler", "QueueableHandler" (these might run in the background and reset the value for whatever reason, if another dev wrote a trigger on accounts for example). And can you set "field history tracking" on this field. If something immediately resets the value it might be recorded in history as 2 events, you setting to "New Donor" and some other code setting it back

Comment: Thanks for trying to help with this. I was able to get the field to update through Process Builder instead of apex.